# Django formsets inlineformset saving to database without foreign key link

Tags: database, django, formsets

I have one disease that is linked to multiple indicators. My problem is that whenever I save my indicators and choose a disease from my dropdown list, a NEW disease will be written to the db that links to the indicators.

I would like to have a drop-down Menu that samples from my Disease table. The user picks a disease and types in indicators. The indicators get saved in the Indicator table with a link to the disease in the Disease table (rather than writing a new disease in the Disease table).

I used this as a reference reference: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/

**Views.py**

```
def drui(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

    diseaseForm  = DiseaseForm(request.POST)

    if diseaseForm.is_valid():
      new_disease = diseaseForm.save(commit=False)
      indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(request.POST, instance=new_disease)

      if indicatorInlineFormSet.is_valid():
         new_disease.save()
         indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(valdrui))

else:
   diseaseForm = DiseaseForm()
   indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(instance=Disease())

return render_to_response("drui.html", {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm, 'indicatorInlineFormSet': indicatorInlineFormSet},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class DiseaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    disease = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Disease.objects.all())
    class Meta:
       model = Disease

class IndicatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Indicator  

IndicatorFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Disease, 
    Indicator,
    can_delete=False,
    extra=MAX_INDICATORS)
```

**HTML:**

```
{{ diseaseForm.as_table }}
{{ indicatorInlineFormSet.as_table }}
```

**Update:**
I got it working using Mariodev's suggestion but only if I put in a PK=1 or some other hard coded number. How do I pass the user selected PK? The choices come from the disease table with PK = id. Here is a snippet of my views.py:

```
def drui(request, id):

    if request.method == "POST":


       disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=id)
       diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST, instance=disease)

       if diseaseForm.is_valid():
          new_disease = diseaseForm.save(commit=False)
          indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(request.POST, instance=new_disease)

          if indicatorInlineFormSet.is_valid():
             new_disease.save()
             indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(valdrui))
```

I get this error when I hit submit: drui() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my first suggestion was wrong. What you should do is display inlineformset in edit view, this way you create instance of DiseaseForm with existing object. So instead of:

```
diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST)
```

You do:

```
disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)
diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST, instance=disease)
```

disease_id taken from url

Comment: I get a "null value in column "disease_id" violates not-null constraint" when i delete that line. Seems like there needs to be some link to the disease table.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works but I'm having trouble with the pk=disease_id portion. How do I pass pk the disease id that the user selected? If I put it the table name (disease) and PK column name (id), I get disease_id as the url and an error message "global name "disease_id" is not defined". The above method definitely works if I put PK=1. It will find the 1st disease row in my table.

Comment: Mariodev, I edited the original question to include what my views.py looks like now. Hope that helps anyone.